# Passing data returned from Request query in Response Post object

Tags: angularjs

My Angular coding is rusty as I haven't done it in a while but what I am trying to do is take a list of values returned from a list controller and inject them into my Response post to a search controller that will use this list to search a repository.

This is what I have tried so far--

1 - initialize the list array with Guid:[] in the $scope.data{} initializer

```
//Initailize 
$scope.data = {
    selection: null,
    start: '',
    end: '',
    minDate: new Date(2017, 01, 01),
    defaultStartDate: moment({ year: currentDate.getFullYear(), month: currentDate.getMonth(), day: currentDate.getDate() }),
    defaultEndDate: moment({ year: currentDate.getFullYear(), month: currentDate.getMonth(), day: currentDate.getDate() + 1 }),
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS',
    elasticUrl: '',
    dnsHost: '',
    messageTypes: [],
    scrollId: '',
    TID: '',
    Guids: []
};
```

2 - return the list that I am interested in from a search controller with  $scope.Guids = data.Guids

```
var search = function () {
    NProgress.start();
    var ospLogsSearchParam = {
        StartDate: $scope.data.start,
        EndDate: $scope.data.end,
        ElasticUrl: $scope.data.elasticUrl,
        MessageTypes: $scope.data.messageTypes,
        DnsHost: $scope.data.dnsHost,
        TID: $scope.data.TID,
    };
    var queryString = $.param(ospLogsSearchParam);
    $http.get("/api/search?" + queryString).success(function (data) {
        $scope.isLoading = false;

        $scope.total = data.Total;
        $scope.took = "";
        $scope.tookMins = "";
        $scope.successCount = "";
        $scope.errorCount = "";
        $scope.tps = "";
        $scope.Guids = data.Guids; (data list)
    }).finally(function () {
        NProgress.done();
    });
}
```

3 - inject this value (Guids: $scope.data.Guids) into the Guids field in the SearchParameter object that I am sending a second search controller.

```
function invokeParse() {
    var ospLogsSearchParam = {
        StartDate: $scope.data.start,
        EndDate: $scope.data.end,
        ElasticUrl: $scope.data.elasticUrl,
        MessageTypes: $scope.data.messageTypes,
        DnsHost: $scope.data.dnsHost,
        TID: $scope.data.TID,
        Guids: $scope.data.Guids (data trying to send to back end controller)
    };
    var parse = {
        Logs: $scope.filteredItems,
        DNSName: !$scope.data.dnsHost ? 'none' : $scope.data.dnsHost,
        OspLogsSearchParams: ospLogsSearchParam
}
```

Expected result is that the back end search controller will perform a search using each value in the list as the where filter.

Actual result is that the guid list is not being populated with that values from the search request.

Comment: The `.success` method has been [removed from the AngularJS framework.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angularjs-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339)

Comment: This is a legacy project that I'm working on and everything else is working fine meaning that the master search is working as is it is when I go to populate the list of guids that I'm having problems.

Comment: Your use of the term "controller" is a bit confusing. How many AngularJS controllers are involved in this? I get the impression that "list controller" is your AngularJS controller and "search controller" is a remote service.

Comment: Just figured it out - I wasn't populating the correct Guid array object I needed to be populating $scope.data.Guids and not data.Guids. Once I did that it started functioning correctly . To clarify the last comment I should have been clearer in my usage of the term 'controller' - it was a backend C# Controller and not an angular controller.